# How to download the most updated file from Sharepoint with VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint

I am having trouble downloading the newest file from a Sharepoint site.

I have a Sharepoint folder with only one file in it. This file will be over written with the same name each time there is an update.

Currently, my code is pulling the old file info even after it is over-written (i'm assuming it is cashed?)

Is there a way to do this with technique? I was thinking about pulling the modified DateTime as well, but that wouldn't rename the actual file?

Stuck on this one! THANKS!!

Here is my code:

```
myURL ="https://SHARPOINTSITE/FILE.jpg"

myPath = "C:\Users\DOMAIN\temp.jpg"
dFile = DownloadFileFromWeb(myURL, myPath)

MainMenu.PictureHolder.Picture = LoadPicture(myPath)     
MainMenu.Repaint
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to take the modified DateTime:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.Path)

End Sub
```

Then, you can probably sort and find a way! :)

The Microsoft reference for FileDateTime is here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264782.aspx